# Next.js 13 Routehandlers redirect doesn't change browser URL

Tags: next.js

How do I change the URL in the addressbar of the browser with a NextResponse.redirect()?

When the user logs out of the /dashboard I would like to change to addressbar to /auth with the redirect in my route.ts file but it stays /dashboard, even though the page content changes and the logout works.

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies })

  await supabase.auth.signOut()


  return NextResponse.redirect(`${requestUrl.origin}/auth`, {
    status: 301,   
  })
}
```

Comment: How you are calling the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling that endpoint via `fetch`? If so, while fetch may follow the redirect, Next.js does not magically switch pages because your fetch request was redirected. You should design your API like this instead:

```
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
   try {
     // logout the user
     return NextResponse.json({ message: "success" });
   } catch (err) {
     // handle your error
     return NextResponse.json({ message: "failed" }, { 
       status: 500,
     });
   }
}
```

From your component you can then call the endpoint and redirect the user from the client side to the desired location using the router hook:

```
"use client";

import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
// or from "next/router" if using pages directory

export default function MyComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const onLogout = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(/* ... */);
      if (!response.ok) throw Error("Logout failed!");
      // or route.replace("/") if you don't want to allow back navigation
      router.push("/");
    } catch {
      // handle error
    }
  }, [router]);

  return <Button onClick={onLogout}>Logout</Button>;
}
```